# Strange "cannot find symbol" error (Compiling package from Terminal)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

**First of all:** *I've read through **all** the `cannot find symbol` threads I could find here. None of them solved the problem I'm facing. I'm not a professional Java Developer and I'm just helping out a colleague with this classes so please go easy on me.*

**Let me describe the basic situation first:**

I have a package called `pdfDownload` located at ***src/pdfDownload***. In this directory I've got 2 files: `PDFItem.java` and `PDFItemParser.java`.

Both are public classes. You can find the code of the classes attached below. I'm using `Eclipse  IDE` shows no warnings nor errors**.

When I compile them I get the following error message:

```
 PDFItemParser.java:19: cannot find symbol symbol  : class PDFItem
 location: class pdfDownload.PDFItemParser  public static
 ArrayList<PDFItem> parseFile(String filePath){
            ^ PDFItemParser.java:11: cannot find symbol symbol  : class PDFItem location: class pdfDownload.PDFItemParser
    ArrayList<PDFItem> items = parseFile("data.csv");    
              ^ PDFItemParser.java:20: cannot find symbol symbol  : class PDFItem location: class pdfDownload.PDFItemParser         ArrayList<PDFItem>
 items = new ArrayList<PDFItem>();      /* Creates an ArrayList from type
 PDFItem which will contain all parsed ItemObjects */
                  ^ PDFItemParser.java:20: cannot find symbol symbol  : class PDFItem location: class pdfDownload.PDFItemParser
        ArrayList<PDFItem> items = new ArrayList<PDFItem>();        /* Creates an
 ArrayList from type PDFItem which will contain all parsed ItemObjects
 */
                  ^ PDFItemParser.java:21: cannot find symbol symbol  : class PDFItem location: class
pdfDownload.PDFItemParser       items.add(new PDFItem());
                      ^ 5 errors
```

The **classes are both public**, **in the correct directory and package**. I **also get auto-completion in Eclipse** for the `PDFItem` inside the `PDFItemParser` class. Me and my colleague have been struggling to solve this for 2 hours now. I'm sorry if it's really easy for you guys but we couldn't solve it because the usual cases for this error didn't apply. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I compile them in the (Mac) Terminal. I open the path in the Terminal, and type in:

```
 javac PDFItem.java
```

and then

```
 javac PDFItemParser.java
```

PDFItem - Class Code:

```
    package pdfDownload;

    public class PDFItem {

        String imageURL;
        String pdfURL;
        boolean imageLoaded;
        boolean pdfLoaded;
        String name;


        public PDFItem() {

        }

        public PDFItem(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }


PDFItemParser - Class Code:
---------------------------

    package pdfDownload;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.io.*;


    public class PDFItemParser {

        public static void main(){

        ArrayList<PDFItem> items = parseFile("data.csv");    

        if(items != null){
            System.out.println(items.get(0).name);
        }
    }


        public static ArrayList<PDFItem> parseFile(String filePath){
            ArrayList<PDFItem> items = new ArrayList<PDFItem>();            /* Creates an ArrayList from type PDFItem which will contain all parsed ItemObjects */
            items.add(new PDFItem());

            try{
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);              /* Get the object of DataInputStream */

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {           /* Read File Line By Line  */

                  System.out.println (strLine);             /* Print the content on the console */

                }
                in.close();             /* Close the input stream */

            }
            catch (Exception e){            /* Catch exception if any */
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return items;               /* Returns ArrayList */
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the command that you're using to compile?

Comment: Do you use any IDE, like Eclipse, Netbeans, ItelliJ, etc?

Comment: @Muel I edited the question and added this info for you.

Comment: @reporter I'm using Eclipse for programming and compile it in the Terminal. (As stated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compile your classes using this command to make sure that your classes go into a folder created for your `package`: -

```
javac -d . PDFItem.java
javac -d . PDFItemParser.java
```

When you compile it without a `-d` flag, then your classes are not inside a `package` folder, where they are actually searched. And hence your `PDFItemParser` is not able to find your `PDFItem` class.

Also, make sure that the you have added the path till your `package folder` in your classpath. Add the path only till the folder with package name, and not till the class name.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the compilation error! I had been searching "man javac" and javac -h for any hints on packages but didn't find this one. :)

Comment: @Tom.. Good, now also make sure that you should use correct main method. It should be `public static void main(String[] args)`. Note the argument that you are missing, else it will give you error at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I've already added it as suggested below. I always thought the arguments were only necessary if you ran it via console and was not sure if somebody will add arguments. Thought they were not needed if you're sure there will be none arguments passed. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: @Tom. whether you pass any argument or not, you should not change the basic syntax of main. If you try to print `args` argument in your main, without passing any argument, you will see that it is not `null`. So actually an array is created. And it is absolutely needed. And You're Welcome :)

Comment: @Tom i didn't get the point, why are you using commandline compilation, if you already does the coding in an IDE like Eclipse ?

Comment: I feel really uncomfortable using Eclipse. I've had lots of trouble with it a few years ago at University. Because I use it once a year or so, I never spent time to configure everything. I just use it for auto-completion. Maybe I should change that for the next project ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you don't have a proper `main` function. Thats all:

I changed this line

```
public static void main(){
```

to

```
public static void main(String args[]){
```

in `PDFItemParser` class

Now i can run the program (But ofcourse it is giving runtime error )

```
Error: data.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)null
```

**EDIT**

This error is expected since i don't have data.csv file.

I am able to compile and run this program without any issue, in eclipse

Comment: The main function is just implemented for testing purposes and will be removed later. I tried adding the parameter but it didn't change the compilation error. So I deleted it again. I'll readd it now. Thanks. :)

Comment: as i mentioned in my **edit**, i can compile and run your program without any issue